# Newton Method for Nonlinear set of Equations

Tags: fortran, newtons-method

I'm a rookie in programming in Fortran90. I used NR method for a system of non-linear equations found in Numerical Recipes and put together a code that does not generate any errors when I compile with GFortran. Problem is, it does not generate any value for output either.
Could it be because my initial guess root value far off from actual root or have I made an error in this code?

Any help/advice on this matter will be highly appreciated.

```
  program main
    implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
    parameter(n=4)   
    logical check
    real*8 x(n),fvec(n),fjac(n)
    open(20,file="output1.txt",status="unknown")
    do i=1,n
      x(i)= 4.
    enddo
    call mnewt(ntrial,x,n,tolx,tolf)    
        call usrfun(x,n,fvec,fjac)
    do i=1,n
      write(20,*) 'x(',i,')=',x(i),fvec(i)
    enddo
  end

subroutine mnewt(ntrial,x,n,tolx,tolf)

integer n,ntrial,np
real*8 tolf,tolx,x(n)
parameter (np=15)
!uses lubksb, ludcmp, usrfun
! Given an initial guess x for a root in n dimensions, take ntrial Newton-Raphson steps to
! improve the root. Stop if the root converges in either summed absolute variable increments
! tolx or summed absolute function values tolf.
integer i,k,indx(np)
real*8 d,errf,errx,fjac(np,np),fvec(np),p(np)

do 14 k=1,ntrial
  call usrfun(x,n,fvec,fjac)
  errf=0.
  do 11 i=1,n
      errf=errf+abs(fvec(i))
  11 continue
  if(errf.le.tolf)return
  do 12 i=1,n
      p(i)=-fvec(i)
  12 continue

  call ludcmp(fjac,n,np,indx,d)
  call lubksb(fjac,n,np,indx,p)

  errx=0.
  do 13 i=1,n
     errx=errx+abs(p(i))
     x(i)=x(i)+p(i)
   13 continue
   if(errx.le.tolx)return

14 continue
return
end

subroutine usrfun(x,n,fvec,fjac)

    implicit none

    integer n
    real*8 x(n),fvec(n),fjac(n,n), hl, ul, br, bl   

hl=1.00
ul=1.00
br=0.20
bl=0.00

! Initial guesses

        x(1)=0.0
        x(2)=1.5
        x(3)=0.5
        x(4)=0.5

    fvec(1)=(x(2))+(2*sqrt((x(1))))-ul-(2*(sqrt(hl)))
    fvec(2)=((x(3))*(x(4)))-((x(1))*(x(2)))
    fvec(3)=((x(3))*(x(4))*(x(4)))+(0.5*(x(3))*(x(3)))-((x(1))*(x(2))*(x(2)))-(0.5*(x(1))*(x(1)))+(0.5*(br-bl)*x(1)+x(3))
    fvec(4)=(x(4))-sqrt((x(3)))

    fjac(1,1)=((x(1))**(-0.5))
    fjac(1,2)=1
    fjac(1,3)=0
    fjac(1,4)=0
    fjac(2,1)=(-x(2))
    fjac(2,2)=(-x(1))
    fjac(2,3)=x(4)
    fjac(2,4)=x(3)
    fjac(3,1)=((x(2))**2)-(x(1))+(0.5)*(br-bl)
    fjac(3,2)=-2*((x(1))*(x(2)))
    fjac(3,3)=((x(4))*(x(4)))+(x(3))+(0.5)*(br-bl)*(x(3))
    fjac(3,4)=2*((x(3))*(x(4)))
    fjac(4,1)=0
    fjac(4,2)=0
    fjac(4,3)=-0.5*((x(3))**(-0.5))
    fjac(4,4)=1

end subroutine usrfun


     subroutine ludcmp(a,n,np,indx,d)  !fjac=a
      integer n,np,indx(n),nmax
      real*8 d,a(np,np),tiny
      parameter (nmax=2500,tiny=1.0e-20)
      integer i,imax,j,k
      real*8 aamax,dum,sum,vv(nmax)

      d=1.
      do 12 i=1,n
        aamax=0.
        do 11 j=1,n
          if (abs(a(i,j)).gt.aamax) aamax=abs(a(i,j))
!   print*,a(21,j)
11      continue
!      print*,i,aamax
!   pause
        if (aamax.eq.0.) pause 'singular matrix in ludcmp'
        vv(i)=1./aamax
12    continue
      do 19 j=1,n
        do 14 i=1,j-1
          sum=a(i,j)
          do 13 k=1,i-1
            sum=sum-a(i,k)*a(k,j)
13        continue
          a(i,j)=sum
14      continue
        aamax=0.
        do 16 i=j,n

          sum=a(i,j)
          do 15 k=1,j-1
            sum=sum-a(i,k)*a(k,j)
15        continue
          a(i,j)=sum
          dum=vv(i)*abs(sum)
          if (dum.ge.aamax) then
            imax=i
            aamax=dum
          endif
16      continue
        if (j.ne.imax)then
          do 17 k=1,n
            dum=a(imax,k)
            a(imax,k)=a(j,k)
            a(j,k)=dum
17        continue
          d=-d
          vv(imax)=vv(j)
        endif
        indx(j)=imax
        if(a(j,j).eq.0.)a(j,j)=tiny
        if(j.ne.n)then
          dum=1./a(j,j)

          do 18 i=j+1,n
            a(i,j)=a(i,j)*dum
18        continue
        endif
19    continue
      return
      end

!lubksb

     subroutine lubksb(a,n,np,indx,b)
      integer n,np,indx(n)
      real*8 a(np,np),b(n)
      integer i,ii,j,ll
      real*8 sum
      ii=0
      do 12 i=1,n
        ll=indx(i)
        sum=b(ll)
        b(ll)=b(i)
        if (ii.ne.0)then
          do 11 j=ii,i-1
            sum=sum-a(i,j)*b(j)
11        continue
        else if (sum.ne.0.) then
          ii=i
        endif
        b(i)=sum
12    continue
      do 14 i=n,1,-1
        sum=b(i)
        do 13 j=i+1,n
          sum=sum-a(i,j)*b(j)
13      continue
        b(i)=sum/a(i,i)
14    continue
      return
      end
```

Comment: If you must copy code from NR you must also (1) insert `implicit none` in all compilation units (to prevent typos declaring new entities); (2) put your subroutines into a `module` and use-associate them (the compiler will check that calls match declarations); and (3) set the `intent` of each procedure argument (mainly to make sure you don't write to arguments you oughtn't to).  Personally I don't even think of looking at code which doesn't incorporate these necessary practices for safe programming, you shouldn't either.

Comment: Thank you. But I doubt whether any of your points are the actual problem. Because I attempted to code the Globally Convergent NR Method, without modules or intent statements, and it worked fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, it is not the *actual* problem but it is a necessity for sane and safe programming in the century. Most importantly, it will tell you, when you use bad arguments when calling a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You provide no values for `ntrial`, `tolx` or `tolf` in your call to `mnewt`. What values do you want the algorithm to use?

Your initial guess with `x(1)=0.0` results in a divide by zero when computing `fjac(1,1)=((x(1))**(-0.5))`.

Your arrays `fjac` and `a` appear to be mis-dimensioned throughout. Surely they should have shape `[n,n]`?

I made the following changes to your code:

```
> diff mine.f90 yours.f90
5c5
<     real*8 x(n),fvec(n),fjac(n,n)
---
>     real*8 x(n),fvec(n),fjac(n)
10c10
<     call mnewt(10,x,n,1.d-6,1.d-6)    
---
>     call mnewt(ntrial,x,n,tolx,tolf)    
68c68
<         x(1)=0.1
---
>         x(1)=0.0
100c100
<       real*8 d,a(n,n),tiny
---
>       real*8 d,a(np,np),tiny
165c165
<       real*8 a(n,n),b(n)
---
>       real*8 a(np,np),b(n)
```

Running my version writes this as output:

```
x( 1 )=   0.1000000014901161  -0.8675444632541631
x( 2 )=   1.5000000000000000   9.9999997764825821E-02
x( 3 )=   0.5000000000000000   0.5299999967962503
x( 4 )=   0.5000000000000000  -0.2071067811865476
```

Is that what you expect?

It took me about five minutes to diagnose these issues by compiling using the NAG Fortran compiler with full runtime checking enabled.

Comment: Thank you MatCross for this very clear explanation. Least I can do is give you a vote (not enough points for this,sorry). However, I noticed that whenever I change my initial conditions at x(n), the output simply comes out to be the initial condition. There seems to be something missing in the code, I'm still trying, I'll post if I find the mistake. Thanks for your effort.